# Brightness not working on MSI GX70

Tags: 16.04, drivers, brightness, radeon, mint

I installed 16.04 LTS on MSI GX70. My display driver is AMD Radeon HD 8650G. In the previous version I could install the display driver using the driver manager.

Now, however, I am not able to do so. I read somewhere that support for the Radeon drivers has been removed. (Is this true?)

In any case, I start my os with the command `radeon.modeset=0`. It works fine, except for the fact that the brightness can't be modified as before.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: What if you boot without `radeon.modeset=0`?

Comment: @Pilot6 It crashes and restarts. Always.

Answer (score 0):

I own a GX60, same APU. I had to add acpi_backlight=video to grub to make the Fn-Keys for brightness work.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight here are more commands you might need to add to your bootloader ;)